# How can I speed up the VS Code performance and Live Preview?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code, live-preview

I have been using my computer for coding till now. My computer has a i3 - 8100 cpu and a RX 550 gpu. I bought a new laptop recently, ASUS Vivobook S15 without OLED. The specs of new laptop are:

- CPU - i5 - 12500H
- Ram - 12 GB
- Graphics - integrated
- Windows 11

My laptop overall performance and Cinebench scores are good. I have been using VS Code for some time now on my computer and whenever I open it in computer it opens in an instant and when I do live preview it works really fast. However, VS Code is giving my new laptop some trouble. It take a minute to open; even Valorant opens faster than VS Code. Also the Live Preview feature takes more time to load, about 5 to 10 seconds, as compared to my old computer where it only takes an instant.

As far as I can tell there is no issue in my ram or SSD; I checked it.
How can I speed VS Code up? Here is what I have tried so far (all unsuccessful):

1. I tried to reinstall it.
2. I tried to remove other extensions but I only use three so it did not had any affect.
3. I tried deleting it from the system completely and then also reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is designed to be pretty simple and minimal, so (as far as I know) there aren't any huge components you can disable and "chop off" to gain startup or general performance other than shed extensions.

The particulars of the performance issues you observe with your Live Preview extension will probably be very isolated to the particulars of your machine and its network capabilities and system task scheduling and current load.